# No Method Error in View & Rails 4 Console with PSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, methods, haml

Can't figure out what's going on as I try to add dirt simple blog capability to my website. Starter app I'm using is pre-configured for HAML and I'm an even bigger HAML n00b than Rails n00b, so I'm seriously struggling.

When I add this to my pages/home.html.haml:

```
%h1= I18n.t('brand.name')
%p
  = I18n.t 'brand.name'

- @posts. each do |post|
  = render 'posts/post', post: post
```

I get:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I can't figure it out... I thought Ruby had an "each" method built it? Why isn't it passing any class in?

Here's the _post.html.haml partial it's trying to render:

```
%p
  %h2
    = link_to post.title, post
%p
  - if post.kind == 'image'
    = image_tag post.content, style: "width: 100%"
  - else
    = simple_format post.content
%p.text-muted
  %small
    Posted on #{post.created_at.to_formatted_s(:long)}
```

And the controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :kind, :content)
    end
end
```

And the model is empty, just:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I copy/pasted most of this code from a working blog example I built in a tutorial and it works fine in that app.

I suspect it has something to do with PSQL (in this app) versus SQLite (in the example app). In rails console, trying it gives the same error:

```
[3] pry(main)> post = post.first
NoMethodError: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass
[4] pry(main)> posts = post.each
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
[5] pry(main)> posts = Post.each
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for Post (call 'Post.connection' to establish a connection):Class
from /Users/troot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
```

I don't understand why the methods that I think should be working are not working here. Thanks so much for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
- @posts. each do |post|
```

there is a space between `@posts` and `each`. There should be no space in between as `each` is a method and you are explicitly calling it using the `.` operator on `@posts` object.
Then in console you are doing:

```
 post = post.first
```

It should be:

```
 post = Post.first
```

The class name should always be in capital. 
And in the console if you need to run `each` then you need to do `Post.all.each` you can use `each` directly on class.

Try correcting this and then check. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the console fix worked! However, the @posts.each fix didn't. I originally had it with no space and then found a HAML example with a space... both give the same result. That the version with a space gives an undefined method error rather than a syntax error indicates that it's recognizing "each" as a method regardless.

Comment: In the above details you have given the `PostController` and in the `index` action you find `@posts` and you are trying to get this in `pages/home.html.haml` so according to rails convention you will get `@posts` in the view listed in `posts/index.html.haml`. So please check if this is so.